# React.js - pass in actual URL with this.props rather than link to localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, localhost, fetch-api

I'm working on a small program in React.js. I am trying to pass in a URL using {this.props}, but instead of linking to the actual webpage, the link leads to the page in localhost. I've been trying to figure out what's happening, but I can't see why the link isn't leading out.

I am building an app that generates a URL that a user clicks on, to lead straight to a jpeg/gif.

JSON URL (random pictures of dogs): https://random.dog/woof.json

Here are my codes:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Search from './components/Search';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dog_URL: undefined,
  }
  getDogs = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://random.dog/woof.json`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    const dog_url = data.url;
    this.setState({
      result_URL: dog_url
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <Search 
            getDogs={this.getDogs} 
        </div>

      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

import React from 'react';

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.getDogs}>
                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search for..." />
                <br />
                <Button> Search </Button>
                <br />
<p> Dog link: <a href="{this.props.dog_url}">{this.props.dog_url}</a> </p>
            </form>
            )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Expected result: user is able to click on link

Actual result: link leads to http://localhost:3000/%7Bthis.props.dog_url%7D

Can anyone give some pointers or suggestions as to why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 4):

```
<p> Dog link: <a href="{this.props.dog_url}">{this.props.dog_url}</a> </p>
```

I do not believe that `"{this.props.dog_url}"` needs to be quoted. Rather, simply `{this.props.dog_url}` ought to work given how JSX variable interpolation works. Is it possible that this might be causing the strange behavior?

Comment: wow, you're right! that completely solved the behavior, I didn't need to put quotes around it at all :)